# Replace characters in string with *, but only characters not spaces JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wanting to mask some paragraph text out until it is hovered, so if I have a string like,

`Hello World`

I would want that to be, `Hell* *****` how can I replace all characters with with a * after 4 characters/letters?

I know I can do all the string like this,

`str.replace(/./g, '*')`

but how can I limit it to after the first 4 letters?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "Hello World"    
var after4= str.substr(0,4)+str.substr(4).replace(/[^\s]/g, '*')

console.log(after4)
```

Comment: [`[^\s] === \S`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types)

Answer (score 0):

I can do this by Splitting String in Two Parts:

1. First Part which would remain as it is.
2. Second Part : I would replace all the Characters by required Character.
3. Concat both the Strings

```js
let text = 'Hello World';

let str1 = text.substring(0, 4);
let str2 = text.substring(4).replace(/\S/g, '*');

let updatedStr = str1.concat(str2);

console.log(updatedStr);

/*
Single Line 

let updatedStr = text.substring(0, 4) + text.substring(4).replace(/\S/g, '*');

*/
```

Regex Info :

- \S : Any other Character other then Space (Capital 'S')

You can combine them in single line Code :

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be capturing the first 4 non whitespace chars using `^(\S{4})` in group 1 and use that in the replacement.

Other non whitespace chars will be matched using an alternation followed by a single non whitspace char `|\S,` and those matches will be returned as `*`

```
^(\S{4})|\S
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iTvXnP/1)

```js
let str = "Hello World"
  .replace(/^(\S{4})|\S/g, (_, g1) => g1 ? g1 : '*');
console.log(str);
```